# AudioKit - how filter out the sound of the guitar

Tags: audiokit

I'm an audioKit beginner and want to make a guitar tuner. now I can catch the frequency from mic, but the Ambient noise is also in it. I don't know how to filter it, does audioKit have relevant filtering methods?

Would appreciate any guidance or help you can give me for this.

Comment: Check out this code: https://github.com/comyar/TuningFork Does some sound processing like smoothing

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could try to band pass filter the mic to only allow the frequency range you're interested in through, but I'm not sure if that will yield better results or not.

Comment: So what does this mean?AKFrequencyTracker.init(microphone, hopSize: 200.0, peakCount: 2000.0)